# iOS Core Plot: Multiple labels for x-axis

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot

Not sure if the is achievable using the Core Plot framework, wondering if anyone has an idea on this? What I want is to have a bar chart with the X-axis having different labels to give additional info as the image below!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Plot can display attributed strings in titles and labels. Create custom axis labels and set the `attributedText` on the label text layer.